# Load one-to-many model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**I have such models:**

```
public partial class Goods
{
    public decimal good_id { get; set; }
    public string good_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Description> description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Description
{
    public decimal des_id { get; set; }
    public decimal des_good_id { get; set; }
    public string des_name { get; set; }
    public string des_value { get; set; }
    public virtual Goods goods { get; set; }
}
```

How can I load all data from the Description model that have same id as good in the view for each good in Goods?

**My Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var parts = _db.Goods.Include(p => p.Details);
    return View(parts.ToList());
}
```

**This thing is not working:**

```
@foreach (var part in Model)
{
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <h3>
                    <strong>@part.good_name</strong>
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    <strong>@part.Description</strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Your question is about retrieving data from your database, but you are not showing the code in which you retrieve this data. Can you please add that code? It will be key to finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in the controller -> action make data and pass it to the model:

```
public ActionResult SampleAction()
{
    using(var context = new YourContext())
    {
        return View(context.Goods.Include("description").First()); // for example    
    }          
}
```

after that you must define your model in View and put it in the first line of the view:

```
@model Goods
```

Then you have all that you needed:
Just render your data:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Model.good_name 
        </td>
    </tr>
@foreach (descp in @Model.description.ToList())
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @desc.des_name
        </td>
        <td>
            @desc.des_value
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: That works fine, thank you! But now I have a question - how to load not only .First() ? I'm trying...but nothing.

Comment: change context.Goods.Include("description").First() to context.Goods.Include("description").ToList(), you will get all data and change **@model Goods** to @model List<Goods> and so on.

Comment: Actually, I got stucked after @model List<Goods> and don't know what to do next. I made another model with field public List<Goods> goods {get; set;} but that didn't help.

Comment: after that you have a list of Goods in the **@Model** and you can iterate on it. @foreach (var g in @Model) { ... } in cshtml.

Comment: but that works only for Goods. Now in html I can do this: @foreach(var good in @Model) { @good.good_name } . Can you, please, explaine to me, how to get details in this way?

Comment: it's obvious, you can use @foreach(var descp in good.description.ToList()) { inside of @foreach(var good in @Model) {

Comment: Should domain logic even be in a controller?

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand your question, You are have model and you also have a list inside your model and your want to retrieve data with list

> Here is your controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var parts = _db.Goods.Include("Descriptions").Where(x=>x.good_id == id);
    return View(parts));
}
```

where "id" is the id on the basis of that your data will be find

> Here is your View code with razor engine

```
 @import YourApplicationName.Model.Goods
 @foreach (var part in @Model.Description)
 {
 <div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <h3>
                <strong>@part.des_name</strong>
            </h3>
            <h4>
                <strong>@part.des_value</strong>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

> Hope this is your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, it would automatically care of loading the related Descriptions for each good. You do not have to do anything specifically for that. You can simply use `goodsInstance.Description`.

Comment: Please, check my edit in main post. I was trying that you said, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are directly trying to Print Description property which is a collection. You have to loop over that collection represented by 'Description'.

Comment: But it isn't possible to request into @Model.Description because the View is strongly typed

Comment: You should be able to loop over Description as shown in the other answer.